# SSL /JS Errors breaking form action on my page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ssl

I have a form on my WordPress site that does a simple math calculation. (I asked the question on WordPress Answers, but did not get a successful solution, I apologize if this is the wrong forum)  When I secure the page (https) the calculation will not work, and I get some errors in my console:

```
[blocked] The page at https://www.disastersafety.org/ofb-ez/risks/risks-form/ ran insecure content from http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js?ver=3.7.1.
 /ofb-ez/risks/risks-form/:1
GET https://www.disastersafety.org/wp-content/themes/snapwire-old/inc/js/script.js?ver=3.7.1 404 (Not Found) www.disastersafety.org:38
[blocked] The page at https://www.disastersafety.org/ofb-ez/risks/risks-form/ ran insecure content from http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js?ver=3.7.1.
```

I am just learning to debug js, but I can't tell if it's the unsecure cdn url causing the problem, or the missing resource: https://www.disastersafety.org/wp-content/themes/snapwire-old/inc/js/script.js?ver=3.7.1 404 (Not Found)

What I do know is that if I do not make the page secure, the form works. And if I deactivate the theme itself and switch to WordPress 2103 theme, the form works even with https. If the theme itself is the problem, I'm not sure how to go about remedying that, so would appreciate suggestions for a newbie.

Thank you so much for your help-

Answer (score 0):

It is because you load resources from an insecure place (http) from a secure place (your WP site with https enabled).

I know that many browsers will block such request (I use Chrome myself, in which I can confirm the behaviour).

If I try to access the resource via https (https://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js?ver=3.7.1) I get an SSL certificate error, and additionally a 404 when ignoring the error.

A possible solution will be to download the script, host on your own secure page, and then link to the "https version" on your own site.

Comment: That's a great idea! Where do I change that link once I have created a page for it? It seems it must be in the theme files, since it all works when I switch themes. Where would that be? Thank you again!

Comment: Just found it in theme-js.php. Going to give it a go!

Comment: Without knowing the exact structure of the theme or the configuration, my best guess would be in: wp-content/themes/<themename>/header.php